# ag grep tool - How to print only the log lines without file name/path in the output?

Tags: shell, grep, ag

I am trying to grep the folder that has lot of files using following **ag command**, and print results with out file name/path.

```
 ag --print-long-lines "test|temp" | grep -Ei  "error|fail"
```

But i still see the file names(sampledata1.txt, sampledata2.txt) in the following output

```
sampledata1.txt test:error 
sampledata2.txt temp:fail
```

Comment: Have you tried `--nofilename` to `ag`?

Comment: Thanks working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ag --nofilename "test|temp"
```